# Parsing Json array stored in string in unity

Tags: arrays, json, unity-game-engine

I have json response stored in string.I want to parse string and store values in array. How to do it in unity?

```
[{"settings":"player_speed","value":"7.0"},
{"settings":"squasher_speed_1","value":"1.0"},
{"settings":"accel_speed","value":"18.0"},
{"settings":"num_lives","value":"5"}]
```

Comment: Did you try `JSON.Parse()`?

Comment: Json.Parse not available in unity.

Comment: https://github.com/tonioloewald/jsonparse

Comment: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON

Comment: Unity has a Json utility -> https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.html

Comment: its not working for arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many things and found answer finally

[Serializable]
    public  class settings_json_parser
    {
        public string settings;
        public string value;
    }

```
 //settings Strings is string which contains json array

    public void parseAndSaveGlobalSettings(string settingsString)
{
    Debug.Log (settingsString);
    settings_json_parser[] playersettings;
    playersettings = JsonHelper.getJsonArray<settings_json_parser>(settingsString);
    for (int i = 0; i < playersettings.Length; i++) {
        playersettings= JsonHelper.getJsonArray<settings_json_parser>(settingsString);
Debug.Log(playersettings[i].settings);
Debug.Log(playersettings[i].value);

    }
```